# Make JOINs with a SQL view with Django ORM

Tags: python, django, join, orm

I'm currently working on a project using Django (1.5.1) and I'm having some problems with the Django ORM.

I have models implemented like below (I only listed those targeting my problem):

```
class Download(models.Model):
    """
    Represents a unit of download with many files
    """
    download_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, primary_key=True, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024, null=False)
```

I had to create a page which lists downloaded files (from Download model) with specific data from other tables.
So I created an SQL view in my database, then I use this view with the following model in Django:

```
class DownloadedFiles(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "file_list"
```

I call it using the following:

```
data = DownloadedFiles.objects.all()
```

I don't have any problem with the view, it returns the results I need so that's fine.

But now I would like to filter my results using fields in other tables than my view.
For example, I would like to filter my results using the 'file_name' field in 'Download' model.
In SQL, this would be something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM file_list
INNER JOIN download ON download.id=file_list.id
WHERE download.file_name LIKE '%something%';
```

I wanted to use ORM functions like

```
DownloadedFiles.objects.filter(download__file_name__contains="something").
```

Unfortunately, as the 'Download' model is not known within my 'DownloadedFiles' model (no reference to it), the Django ORM is unable to make any relationship.
Also, I cannot find a method which works to explicitly create JOINs.
Googling it gave some ways but no one works (all thrown exceptions):

- Using extra(): `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'download' into field. Choices are: file_name, added_date, id`.
- Using join() (http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/): `DatabaseError: column download.id does not exist`.
- Adding some foreign keys to my view's model in order to have relationships with other tables: same as extra().

Maybe I badly implemented these solutions, or they are completely useless in my case.
I would like to know if someone already faced this situation and how to solve it.

Thank you

Comment: Your proposed syntax `filter(mission__place_name__contains="something")` should work just as it is. What happens when you try that?

Comment: I simplified my examples and also precised my problem: in fact, as the DownloadedFiles model has no reference to Download model, Django ORM seems unable to resolve `download__file_name__contains`. The error thrown is the same as when I tried extra(): `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'download' into field. Choices are: file_name, added_date, id`

Comment: You've possibly oversimplified: now there's no matching fields at all between Download and DownloadedFiles. What's the relationship?

Comment: In fact, only the id is common in this specific case. But I should be able to make joins between the view and any other models I created, starting from the view. The goal is to keep the view to get all results, then filtering these results using joins and where clauses on other tables.